# What is the correct way to store data N with associated properties if I've 100s of N to track?

Tags: dictionary, python-2.7

For each stock symbol N, I have 4 associated properties such as status, current price, world ranking and historical prices. Right now, i am storing the values in the form of a dictionary {}.

> > {'Status': 'Active', 'Historical Price': '30, 31, 35', 'Rank': '3', 'Symbol N': 'AIG', 'Price': '$30.5'}

As I will be iterating through many stocks N, it seems that dictionary may not be the ideal method to store such data. What is the correct way to do what I am trying to do?

---

Fundamentally, I am looking for a list of dictionaries. Does it make sense?

Comment: Why is it not ideal? Too slow or inefficient? A hash table may do the trick assuming that all stock symbols are unique.

Comment: I have no idea how to call for the values associated with each symbol N. In a list, i could use list[0], list[1], list[2], ... to call for the value but i don't know how to do so in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a stock called AIG, you could do something like this to make it simple:

```
stocks = {}
stocks['AIG.Status'] = 'Active'
stocks['AIG.Historical Price'] = '30,31,35'
stocks['AIG.Rank'] = '3'
stocks['AIG.Symbol N'] = 'AIG'
stocks['AIG.Price'] = '$30.5'
```

or

```
stocks = {}
stocks['AIG'] = ['Active','30,31,35','3','AIG','$30.5']
```

and then use

```
stocks['AIG'][0]
stocks['AIG'][1]
```

to iterate over a dictionary just use this on the second example:

```
for stock in stocks:
    print stocks[stock]
```

Comment: I like the second method because I could use an [x][y] matrix format to call for the value. Thanks.

Comment: Ignore last message. Fixed it.